# Accessing Microsoft Access 2003 and 2007 BLOB fields from .Net

Tags: c#, ms-access, blob

I need to be able to extract BLOBs from both Access 2003 and Access 2007. Access 2003 stores BLOBs as "OLE Objects", and Access 2007 gives you another option, "Attachment". The major difference is that multiple attachments can added to a single row, whereas there can be only one BLOB per "OLE Object" data type.

I have to be able to do this without using interop as I cannot force the dependency of having Office installed. That leaves me with either DAO or ADO. So I have written the code to use both technologies to pull the BLOBs out of a test database with loads of different types of file types embedded.

The problem I have is that it seems Access wraps the embedded files in some type of meta data. The net result is that the file, once extracted, is no longer the same and can not be opened by the associated application because its "corrupted". Access stores things like the original file name and so forth in this meta data. I need to be able to strip that meta data off of the files to have the file in its original state.

Is there some dark voodoo magic which can do this? There is very little by way of documentation on this subject. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say ADO, do you mean ADODB.Stream ?

Comment: In Jet/ACE, BLOBs and OLE fields are two distinct data types. The former is a pure binary field with arbitrary data stored in it according to your needs. The OLE field, on the other hand, has a standard wrapper around the binary content that controls how the object embedded there is opened and manipulated.

Comment: I'm not sure you can accomplish what you need to do without automation. Have you looked at Stephen Lebans' OLE extraction utility? http://www.lebans.com/oletodisk.htm -- the code in that database might give you some ideas about how it is done within Access, and thus might give you clues as to what's possible without automation (or not).

Comment: Thanks for the tip re OleToDisk. I'll have a look and see what I can come up with. Apart from that I have found bits and pieces which describe stripping the first X bytes from the byte array depending on file type, which may be what I need to do to get this working. Problem is that it's like poking around in the dark as there is no spec on what is actually happening when the file is wrapped.

Comment: I hear you. I had a project were we stored documents of all types (Word, Excel, Powerpoint) in OLE fields, and when it came time to migrate to a different application, we couldn't pull the data out. Most of it was stale by that time, so they didn't bother, but it confirmed for me that storing documents in the database is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This occours because OLE objects are stored like "images" on Access. This leads to performance issues, also problems like yours. To deal with these limitations, Microsoft introduced Attachment fields on Access 2007/2010, wich doesn't need OLE servers to run content. Attachments, wich should be more than one file per record, are automaticaly managed in backstage by MS-Access. Maybe you should use Attachments or change your database for SQL Server, MY-SQL, Firebird.